# R: how to drop rows from a data frame if the rows contain a certain value (for many columns)

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with many variables (columns) and rows (observations). I want to drop rows that contain the value `1` from my dataframe.

I know I can, given

```
      X Y
    1 1 1
    2 2 1
    3 3 1
    4 4 4
    5 5 5
```

do this:

```
    test <- data.frame("X"=1:5, "Y"=c(1,1,1,4,5))

    test[test$X>1 & test$Y>1, ]
```

and get:

```
      X Y
    4 4 4
    5 5 5
```

But I don't want to write out `data$var1 > 1 & data$var2 > 1 ...` for 20 or 50 variables to do something so simple.

How can I get the same result without having to do a lot of writing?

---

Edit: **Big oof**: none of the three methods suggested here produces the same amount of observations. Is this a bug? Maybe it is some effect of interactions with NA?

Method 1)

```
df[!apply(df[, myCols], 1, function(x) any(x == 1)),]

> any(df == 1)
[1] TRUE
```

Method 2)

```
removeRowsWithOnes <- function(df) {
  rowsToRemoveIndices <- rowSums(df == 1) > 0
  return(df[!rowsToRemoveIndices,])
}

> any(df == 1)
[1] NA
```

Method 3) (removes a different amount of rows than method 2))

```
require(tidyverse)

df %>% 
    filter(
        across(everything(), ~ . != 1)
    )

> any(df == 1)
[1] NA
```

Edit 2: After adding NAs to df:

```
df <- data.frame("x"=c(1,NA,2,2,3,NA), "y"=c(NA,1,1,4,NA,NA))

   x  y
1  1 NA
2 NA  1
3  2  1
4  2  4
5  3 NA
6 NA NA
```

Only method 3) produces the expected result:

```
   x  y
1  2  4
2  3 NA
3 NA NA
```

---

Edit 2:

See @Jonas's comment:

> To make the two methods work, you can add na.rm=TRUE to the call of rowSums and any. This option is by default set to na.rm=FALSE (see the documentation)

Comment: This is mainly because `any(x == 1)` returns `NA` if `x` contains `NA`, as it is not possible to compare `NA` with an `integer`. This is essentially the same story for method 2.

Method 3 directly asks whether the value is `NA` and retains it if it is `TRUE`, while retaining values different from 1 at the same time. The remaining methods do not directly ask whether the value is `NA`.

Comment: To make the two methods work, you can add `na.rm=TRUE` to the call of `rowSums` and `any`. This option is by default set to `na.rm=FALSE` (see the documentation)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out @Jonas, I was not aware of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another possible answer is using `tidyverse`

```
require(tidyverse)

df %>% 
    filter(
        across(everything(), ~ . != 1)
    )
```

Which retains rows that are different from 1, across **all** variables that you have in your data frame.

**Note:** If you have `NA` in your data, this approach will remove those indices as well. Therefore I suggest the following extension;

```
df %>% 
    filter(
        across(everything(), ~ . != 1 | is.na(.))
    )
```

Then it retains **all** values different from 1 without dropping `NA` rows. Otherwise you will potentially drop rows that you meant to keep (Depending on whatever you are doing).

**Comparing Running Times**

Following the example of Jonas, I tried to do a benchmark of all the solutions;

```
# Using rowSums
removeRowsWithOnes <- function(df) {
    rowsToRemoveIndices <- rowSums(df == 1) > 0
    return(df[!rowsToRemoveIndices,])
}

# Using apply
removeRowsWithOnes2 <- function(df) {
    df[!apply(df, 1, function(x) any(x == 1)),]
}

# Using tidyversr
removeRowsWithOnes3 <- function(df) {df %>% 
    filter(
        across(everything(), ~ . != 1 | is.na(.))
    )}
```

*The Benchmark*

```
n <- 1e5
set.seed(5555)
bigSampleData <- do.call("cbind",lapply(LETTERS, function(nam) setNames(data.frame(sample(1:1000,n,replace = TRUE)),nam)))
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(removeRowsWithOnes(bigSampleData),removeRowsWithOnes2(bigSampleData),removeRowsWithOnes3(bigSampleData),times=10)
```

*The Results*

```
Unit: milliseconds
                               expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval cld
  removeRowsWithOnes(bigSampleData)  35.57471  40.54827  77.64570  41.06107  60.34422 217.3363    10  b 
 removeRowsWithOnes2(bigSampleData) 217.34171 222.35136 227.90565 227.05570 229.02625 240.9274    10   c
 removeRowsWithOnes3(bigSampleData)  17.42338  22.24363  23.34607  22.88563  23.72934  32.0293    10 a
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `apply`:

```
df[!apply(df[, myCols], 1, function(x) any(x[!is.na(x)] == 1)),]
```

where `myCols` is vector of column names for which you want to discard row if they contain 1. If all columns should be considered then replace `df[, myCols]` with `df`.

Comment: I actually tried using ´apply(test, 1, function(x) x > 1)´, I don't understand why using ´any()´ outputs one row and not two; is it something R does behind scenes? i.e. it picks up when ´any()` is called? R knows to sum a whole vector when ´any()´ but does it element by element otherwise?

Comment: The `any`-function takes a vector of `logicals` and returns `TRUE` iff at least one value in the vector is `TRUE`, otherwise it returns `FALSE`. It doesn't matter how large the vector (in your case the row of the dataframe) is, it always retruns one `logical`-value.

Comment: There's still rows with 1 in my dataset after this attempt at filtering, any ideas why?

Comment: can you provide example? You need to be careful when working with rows because values can be different type (type conversion).

Comment: They're all of type integer. There are NAs in the dataset, that's the only thing I can think of to cause this.

Comment: I've added `NA` cases update but im not sure thats the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the following function:

```
removeRowsWithOnes <- function(df) {
  rowsToRemoveIndices <- rowSums(df == 1) > 0
  return(df[!rowsToRemoveIndices,])
}
```

This function uses Rs highly optimized `rowSums`-function and a nice comparison feature when dealing with dataframes.

To give some benchmark, lets put det's answer in another function:

```
removeRowsWithOnes2 <- function(df) {
  df[!apply(df, 1, function(x) any(x == 1)),]
}
```

Now run a benchmark on a big sample data.

```
n <- 1e5
set.seed(5555)
bigSampleData <- do.call("cbind",lapply(LETTERS, function(nam) setNames(data.frame(sample(1:1000,n,replace = TRUE)),nam)))
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(removeRowsWithOnes(bigSampleData),removeRowsWithOnes2(bigSampleData),times=10)
```

On my machine, it gives the following results:

```
Unit: milliseconds
                               expr      min       lq     mean    median       uq      max neval
  removeRowsWithOnes(bigSampleData)  59.6315  60.9947  78.8833  72.17005  88.4460 132.6954    10
 removeRowsWithOnes2(bigSampleData) 352.3655 370.9296 416.3392 425.06935 442.7583 493.9709    10
```